# Adwords API for target Ideas is not providing average cpc value and reach for certain keywords

Tags: reactjs, keyword, google-ads-api, targeting

I use TargetingIdeaService  generate new keyword ideas based on the following parameters:

```
searchParameters: [{
                'xsi:type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
                queries: [<query>]
            }, {
                'xsi:type': 'LanguageSearchParameter',
                languages: [{ 'cm:id': <languageId> }]
            },
            {
                'xsi:type': 'LocationSearchParameter',
                locations: [{ 'cm:id': <locationId >}]
            }
        ],
        ideaType:<ideaType>,
        requestType: 'IDEAS',
        requestedAttributeTypes: ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'AVERAGE_CPC', 'COMPETITION', 'SEARCH_VOLUME', 'COUNTRY'],
        paging: {
            startIndex: 0,
            numberResults: <numberResults>
        }
```

I provided search query parameter as a seed keyword
But i get the result with some keywords missing the average cpc ,comeptition,search volume.

Even if I try using requestType as STATUS also i dnot get the details.

And i tried the KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT of the customer account to get the keyword details if it is already using one.But i cannot find the details in the report too.

Please suggest a way to get the keyword cpc,reach resulted by the targeting idea service api.